# How to deactivate automatic mobile view on Amazon.com?

Tags: amazon

I'm using latest Opera Mini on an Nokia E61i and when visiting Amazon it stubbornly persists to switch automatically to a reduced mobile version. That's really annoying because I need even more clicks to get all information (read: to get the full product information it needs another load when already on the product due reduced information presented). I'd rather wait longer to load a bigger page than to load multiple pages.

So, is there a way to switch to normal view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Blackberry browser, at the bottom of every mobile page is a link to the full version.

It looks like it just appends `&force-full-site=1` to the end of the URL.

ex. http://www.amazon.com/?ie=UTF8&force-full-site=1

If you're looking for a way to completely disable the mobile version you would have to set your mobile browser to identify itself as a desktop browser. That is, spoof the user-agent in Opera Mini (no idea if that's possible, it is on my BB).

The Amazon website appears to redirect based on the user-agent of the browser, and can be overridden by the url option.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble getting from a mobile version of a product link to the full site on a PC. I eventually discovered that changing the `/aw/d/` section to `/product/` retrieved the full site. I don't know if this will work for a mobile browser.

for example:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00AX4YF6I
```

to:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00AX4YF6I
```

the important part actually seems to be `/aw/`. The site still works with or without the `/d/`, but it seems to change the style. I'm not really sure what the purpose is.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon [has this to say](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/fp.html?id=fs) about accessing the full site from a mobile platform:

> How To Access Amazon.com Full Site: If you routinely use the full Amazon.com site rather than this mobile site, you may wish to bookmark the URL [**www.amazon.com/fullsite**](http://www.amazon.com/fullsite) in your mobile browser.